# OData: How to add operations for get by id?

Tags: azure-api-management

My swagger.json on the backend lists two different paths for each operation like so:

```
"paths": {
    "/api/Clients": { 
    ...
    "/api/Clients({key}: {"
    ...
```

When I try to edit the OpenAPI markup directly and add new path, it says duplicate path.
I also tried adding {key} as an optional parameter to the existing Clients opeartion, but it didnt like being marked optional, but having the value come from the path. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897254/azure-api-management-issue-with-odata/54912065#54912065) it looks like its possible, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post that you shared, the recommendation was to use a path like `/api/Clients/{key}` and then [rewrite the URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#RewriteURL) as required.

To be exact to the recommendation, you could go for `/api/{entity}/{key}` itself, catching all entities.