# Odata $metadata routing with Azure API Management and adding route in Swagger

Tags: api, .net-core, odata, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I am running into a trouble putting an existing Web API project and creating a OData enabled new end point. Although most of the filters work in local and in APIM the `/$metadata` seemed to be not working. While hosting the API in .netCore 2.2 in AAM the `/$metadata` route getting generated related to the Azure hosted Web App and not that of Azure API Management. We thought of adding it to swagger definition explicitly but we were unable to do that too for `/$metadata` and as such getting 404 resource not found error while trying to access it? The `/$metadata` endpoint doesn't even follow the controller and action method pattern. It's like
`

> Blockquote

[https://abc.azure.net/$metadata#ddd`](https://abc.azure.net/$metadata#ddd%60) or
`https://abc.azure.net/$metadata`

structure.

I can't get over the feeling I've missed something here. Is there a way of defining some sort of wildcard portion to the operation? I can't find anything like that in the AAM documentation. I kept on thinking is there anything I need to do but I am now out of ideas so request if someone can point me in right direction that why the routes generated after deploying to AAM it is of web app normal route rather than AAM API routes?

Comment: Did you try manually defining operation in APIM with URL template of "/$metadata"?

Comment: I created route explicity for swagger as APIM was generating route based on the swagger definition. I was getting error because of API +OData route saying two get operatwith same operation Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL template of APIM supports wildcard. Here is a similar which might be helpful for your scenario [Azure API Management issue with OData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897254/azure-api-management-issue-with-odata)

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am facing the issue more about hostname in the route generated by Odata for the $metadata endpoint.

the route for end point should have the host like :
[link]https://dev-api.platforms.xyz.com.in/v1/$metadata#ddd

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I am facing the issue more about hostname in the route generated by Odata for the $metadata endpoint.

the route for end point should have the host like :
[link]https://dev-api.platforms.xyz.com.in/v1/$metadata#ddd

but it is generating route of azure web app instead of AAM endpoint route like
[link]https://abc-dev-api.azurewebsites.net/v1/$metadata#ddd

Requesting for any kind suggestion. Spent hours trying to resolve the issue but couldn't find the reason and if I have missed out anything.

Comment: maybe you can forward the APIM hostname to the azure web app so that the web app can generate correct url, like what this sample does. https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Forward%20gateway%20hostname%20to%20backend%20for%20generating%20correct%20urls%20in%20responses.policy.xml